# Simple rails integration with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Having trouble rendering first page using rails and backbone. Please assume that I have all the gems properly installed and running. Most of the coffeescript files are generated using 'rails g backbone:scaffold Student', but I changed some files and directory structure. This is just to try to understand the process flow than anything else. I also loaded some student data in db. Finally, when this rails application is deployed (development) and I visit localhost:3000, I don't get the alert that is in initialize function.

Here are the files.

---

app/models/students.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dob, :email, :name, :phone_number
end
```

---

app/controllers/students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    respond_with (@students = Student.all)
  end
end
```

---

config/routes.rb

```
School::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :students

  root :to => 'students#index'
```

---

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>School</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <tbody>
    <div id="students">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

---

app/views/students/index.html.erb

```
<%= content_for :javascript do %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.School.initialize({ students: <%= @students.to_json %> });
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min
//
//= require underscore
//= require json2
//= require backbone
//= require backbone_rails_sync
//= require backbone_datalink
//= require backbone-forms
//= require school
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/school.js.coffee

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ../templates
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./collections
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers

window.School =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
  initialize: (data) -> alert 'Hello for rails'
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/collections/students.js.coffee

```
class School.Collections.StudentsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: School.Models.Student
  url: '/students'
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/models/student.js.coffee

```
class School.Models.Student extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'student'
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/routers/students_router.js.coffee

```
class School.Routers.StudentsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @students = new School.Collections.StudentsCollection()
    @students.reset options.students

  routes:
    "index"    : "index"
    ".*"       : "index"

  index: ->
    @view = new School.Views.Students.IndexView(students: @students)
    $("#students").html(@view.render().el)
```

---

app/assets/javascripts/views/students/index_view.js.coffee

```
School.Views.Students ||= {}

class School.Views.Students.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["templates/students/index"]

  initialize: () ->
    @options.students.bind('reset', @addAll)

  addAll: () =>
    @options.students.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (student) =>
    view = new School.Views.Students.StudentView({model : student})
    @$("tbody").append(view.render().el)

  render: =>
    @$el.html(@template(students: @options.students.toJSON() ))
    @addAll()

    return this
```

---

app/assets/templates/students/index.jst.ejs

```
<h1>Listing students</h1>

<table id="students-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

html output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>School</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/students.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/json2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone_rails_sync.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone_datalink.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-forms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/school.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/students/edit.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/students/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/students/new.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/students/show.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/students/student.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/models/student.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/collections/students.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/students/edit_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/students/index_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/students/new_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/students/show_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/views/students/student_view.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/routers/students_router.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="46vcYK8H3HIUfZh9wfu+AtzCKs+/2TnESA2ILxhFx0E=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
  <tbody>
  <div id="students">

  </div>
  </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Changing app/views/students/index.html.erb to below code solves the problem  `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.Sepms.initialize({ students: <%= @students.to_json.html_safe -%> });
  });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems that are seemingly related and unrelated at the same time.

1. The reason your index doesn't render correctly is because you have a content block for a a named yield that doesn't exist.
   To get `<%= content_for :javascript do %>` to work, add the following to `application.html.erb`:

   `<%= yield :javascript %>`

   However, this will get your code to display, it most likely will not get it to run correctly.
2. Since you are using the **rails-backbone** gem and leveraging the use of templates, you simply need to have the following in your index.html.erb:

   ```
    <div id="students"></div>
   ```

And then instantiate your backbone router in your *index.html.erb* by using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   try {
     window.SchoolRouter = new School.Routers.StudentsRouter({ students: <%= @students.to_json %> });
     backbone.history.start();
   }catch(e){
     alert(e); // alert so that you see it.
   }
  });
</script>
```

When it comes to JavaScript, make sure you're using FireBug or the Dev panels in your browser. *console.log()* is your best friend.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use script tags? I realize this is a bit of a chicken egg... but isn't there a way to have the app initialized in the rails asset pipeline way? #nomorescripttags

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If there was, it almost seems like an unnecessary abstraction for a rather simple issue. If you're using coffeescript though in your rails, you could use the `$ ->` to signify the same thing as onDocumentReady().

Comment: I think we can add `//= require backbone/init` to our application.js file, and then put all this initialization code in `app/assets/javascript/backbone/init.js`. That's the pattern I've adopted in my projects. I think I will add a detailed description of my setup as an alternative answer.